# Check multiple conditions based on grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

Example sample table from a large table:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SiteLocation': ['1234 something street','1234 something street','1234 something street','1234 something street', '1234 something street','1234 something street', '567 other street', '567 other street', '567 other street', ],
          'Boolean': ['true','false','false','false','false','false', 'false','true','false'],
         'Active?': ['Cake-active','Pie-active','Cake-inactive','KeyLime-active', 'Vanilla Sundae-active', 'Pie-inactive', 'Cake-active','Cake-inactive','KeyLime-inactive']})
```

| SiteLocation | Boolean | Active? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 something street | true | Cake-active |
| 1234 something street | false | Pie-active |
| 1234 something street | false | Cake-inactive |
| 1234 something street | false | KeyLime-active |
| 1234 something street | false | Vanilla Sundae-active |
| 1234 something street | false | Pie-inactive |
| 567 other street | false | Cake-active |
| 567 other street | true | Cake-inactive |
| 567 other street | false | KeyLime-inactive |

My goal: I’d like to create a ‘Found?’ column that returns ‘Found’ if a SiteLocation has any `true` in column `Boolean` and should not have `Pie-Active` in column `Active?`.

In this example, SiteLocation '567 other street' would get flagged as 'found'. See below for what I mean:

| SiteLocation | Boolean | Active? | Found? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 something street | true | Cake-active | Not Found |
| 1234 something street | false | Pie-active | Not Found |
| 1234 something street | false | Cake-inactive | Not Found |
| 1234 something street | false | KeyLime-active | Not Found |
| 1234 something street | false | Vanilla Sundae-active | Not Found |
| 1234 something street | false | Pie-inactive | Not Found |
| 567 other street | false | Cake-active | Found |
| 567 other street | true | Cake-inactive | Found |
| 567 other street | false | KeyLime-inactive | Found |

Although `1234 something street` has `true` in column `Boolean`, in column `Active?` it has `Pie-active` not satisfied the condition.

Comment: why you are getting `Not Found` at index 0 bcz your condition satisfies there?

Comment: No it doesn’t because Pie-active is found at SiteLocation 1234 Somewhere street. The SiteLocation would need to both have a true and NO Pie-active to be Found

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.where (Condition, SolutionIfCondition, SolutionIfNotCondition)`. Still others pop up. Maybe give an alternative to `df['Active?'] != 'Pie-active'`

```
df['status']=np.where(((df['Boolean']== 'true') & (df['Active?'] != 'Pie-active')),'Found','blaaah')
```

Comment: Thanks! How does this know how to categorize the flag for each SiteLocation?

Comment: As explained here `np.where (Condition, SolutionIfCondition, SolutionIfNotCondition)`. This `(df['Boolean']== 'true')` gives you a Boolean return `` this `df['Active?'] != 'Pie-active')`also gives you a boolean return. When the two are combined, if `true` Found is written. If `false` `bl`aa` is written

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method. For example your `status` column can be created as follows.

```py
df['status'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'Found' 
    if (x['Boolean']=='true' and x['Active?'] != 'Pie-active') 
    else 'NotFound', axis=1)
```

The advantage is that you can refactor and update the logic to write complex user defined function and pass it through the `apply`. For example the above code can also be refactored as

```py
def is_found(x):
    if x['Boolean']=='true' and x['Active?'] != 'Pie-active':
        return 'Found'
    else:
        return 'NotFound'

# Use the function in apply
df['status'] = df.apply(lambda x: is_found(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. How does this know how to categorize the flag for each SiteLocation?

Comment: By your question, the first street location must also be found since the first row has `Boolean` value is `true` and `Active?` value as `Cake-active`.  So the entire column will become `Found`. If that is not intended, update the question carefully.

Answer (score 1):

1. find the target SiteLocation
2. then fill the target SiteLocation with 'Found', other with 'Not Found'

```
cond1 = df['Boolean'] == 'true'
cond2 = df['Active?'] == 'Pie-active'
site_list = set(df.loc[cond1, 'SiteLocation']) - set(df.loc[cond2, 'SiteLocation'])
df['Found?'] = np.where(df['SiteLocation'].isin(site_list), 
                        'Found', 'Not Found')
```

Comment: Thanks, I’m only looking for ‘Pie-active’ under the ‘Active?’ Column so I modified your 3rd cond to cond &= df[‘Active’] != ‘Pie-active’.

Comment: Got it. You mean the `SiteLocation` should have a  true `Boolean` and not any `Pie-active` in `Active?`. These are two conditions separately.

Comment: Yes that’s correct. Sorry for the confusion and thanks again